# why is 0 not taken as int in this exception handling code?

Tags: c++, exception

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace  std;
void tryl(int test){
    try{
        if(test)
        throw(test);
        else
        throw "it is a string\n";
    }catch(int i){
        cout<<"exception caught int"<<"\n";

    }
    catch(char const *str){
        cout<<"exception string"<<"\n";
    }
}
int main(){
    tryl(1);
    tryl(2);
    tryl(0);
    
}
```

in this code,when 0 is passed as an argument in the tryl function,it throws an exception which is caught by catch which has parameter const char*str but shouldnt it be caught by catch with parameter int as 0 is an integer?

Comment: Let me ask you, what does `if(0)` mean?  Do you run `throw(test);` or do you run `else throw "it is a string\n";`?

Comment: This could be solved by running the program in a debugger and stepping through the execution.

Comment: yeah i got it if 0 is passed if condition will be false thus else will run which will throw a string. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Because if(test) is evaluated as false (if(0) or if(false)) so it jumps to the else block where in the end the exception "it is a string" is thrown...

If I understood correctly the solution to your problem would be:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace  std;
void tryl(int test){
    try{
        if(isdigit(test)){
          throw(test);
        }else{
          throw "it is a string\n";
        }
    }catch(int i){
        cout<<"exception caught int"<<"\n";

    }catch(char const *str){
        cout<<"exception string"<<"\n";
    }
}

int main(){
    tryl(1);
    tryl(2);
    tryl(0);
}
```

Comment: None of the given test arguments will cause the `isdigit(test)` to evaluate to true. That function evaluates the (normally) ASCII representation of its argument.

Answer (score 0):

Comments already ment1ion what is wrong. `if(0)` is false. You should use [`std::is_integral`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral) . I would suggest  [`std::is_arithmetic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_arithmetic) if you wanna include floats also.